# How to fix this COUNT query data using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

i have two table galang_dana and donasi, and then i'm try to count all data inside the galang_dana table, and donasi table. The data in galang_dana table is there 6 data, when i'm try this query it's show the data correctly there 6 data

```
select count(galang_dana.id_galang_dana) as jumlah_galang_dana
from galang_dana
```

but when i'm try to inner join that both table using this query to count and sum the other data, the data of query  **select count(galang_dana.id_galang_dana) as jumlah_galang_dana**  its showing 8 data.

```
select count(galang_dana.id_galang_dana) as jumlah_galang_dana,
       count( distinct donasi.id_user) as jumlah_donatur,
       SUM(donasi.jumlah_dana) as total_dana_terkumpul
from `galang_dana` left join
     `donasi`
     on `galang_dana`.`id_galang_dana` = `donasi`.`id_galang_dana`
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help in understanding what you want to do.

Comment: probably because some `galang_dana.id_galang_dana` exist more than one time inside `donasi.id_galang_dana` column

Comment: You could also `count distinct galang_dana.id_galang_dana`

Comment: @krishKM omg, i'm forgot the distinct , thankyou sir!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to aggregate *before* joining:

```
select gd.jumlah_galang_dana,
       d.jumlah_donatur, d.total_dana_terkumpul
from (select count(*) as jumlah_galang_dana
      from `galang_dana` gd
     ) gd cross join
     (select count(distinct d.id_user) as jumlah_donatur,
             sum(d.jumlah_dana) as total_dana_terkumpul
      from donasi d
     ) d;
```

Comment: Thankyou it's work for me! but, do you know how to implement this query using query builder laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('galang_dana')
    ->selectRaw('
       COUNT(*) jumlah_galang_dana,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM donasi WHERE donasi.id_galang_dana = galang_dana.id_galang_dana) jumlah_donatur,
       (SELECT SUM(`jumlah_dana`) FROM donasi WHERE donasi.id_galang_dana = galang_dana.id_galang_dana) total_dana_terkumpul
    ')
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->get();
```